# postgresql query to get active items in time periods

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the following structure:

> users:
>
> id::uuid, created::timestamp, deleted::timestamp

and I'm trying to query how many users where active monthly, my current query:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', created) as activity_month, count(1)::int4 as activity_count 
  FROM users u
  WHERE 
     created >= '2021-01-01'
     AND created <= '2021-12-31'
  group by date_trunc('month', created);
```

Wished result:

```
'2021-01-01' | 102
'2021-02-01' | 141
'2021-03-01' | 69
...
```

I think I need to create some kind of sub query to find the active users of a month (users that are created but not deleted or deleted in that month) and then group them... but I actually have no idea how to do that. One Problem I have are users created and deleted in the same month.
Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: can you try `count(*) as activity_count `?

Comment: count(1) and count(*) are the same in this case :)

Answer (score 0):

> (users that are created but not deleted or deleted in that month)

So, you want users that were created, but not deleted in that month. In that case it seems you should only add that condition:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', created) as activity_month, count(1)::int4 as activity_count 
  FROM users u
  WHERE 
     (created between '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31')
     AND ( 
          (deleted > created + '1 month'::interval ) 
          OR
          deleted IS NULL
          )
  group by date_trunc('month', created)
```

So this should select only users who were created past year, but either not deleted at deleted more than 1 month after creation.

Comment: with this query the users created n months ago and deleted in that month are not counted. For a single month the query would be: " select count(*) from users u where created <= '2021-01-31' and (deleted is null or (deleted<= '2021-01-31' or deleted >= '2021-01-01'));"

Comment: @BarNiy do you have users that can be deleted before created? if not then shouldn't just changing ">" to ">=" in my query work?